# How can i echo the name of a button what i pressed?

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm using a `for` cycle that creates as many buttons as many names are in my database.

```
 $result = $db->query("SELECT `username` FROM `vote`");
            for ($i=0; $i < $result->rowcount(); $i++) {
```

And every button has a name fetched from the database.

```
<button name="<?php echo $Class->FileName[$i];?>"
```

I want to save the name of a button into a variable after it's pressed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say you want to save the name of the button into a variable... do you mean a PHP variable? You'll need a form submission and `$_POST` for that.

Comment: If you respond to the questions, it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: You either have to submit the form (to get the $_GET or $_POST variable) or you have to perform an Ajax request to get the name of the button name

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes, into a php variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the name of the button in the $_POST variable. Will return true if submited.

```
if($_POST['mi-button']){$button='mi-button';}
```

Comment: that's oke, but i have a dynamic system and the number of the buttons are change sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control space-bottom" onclick="getHistory(this.value)" id="animal" style="width:40%;display:block;margin-auto;margin-top:70px;margin-left:300px"name="target" required>
<?php
         foreach($patients_rows as $key0 => $value0){
             $name = implode(' ',$value0);
             unset($value0['history'],$value0['ID']);
             $aj = implode(' ', $value0);
             foreach($value0 as $key =>$value){
                 if($key == 'pet_name'){
                     echo '<option " value="'.$aj.'">'.$aj.'</option>';
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
</select>
```

Would be like this but with buttons instead of select/option

Comment: Thats good but i dont need a select. I just want to save the name of a button into a php variable like     $buttonname = xy;